# How to change values in array according to specified condition?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I try to put a condition in the array which if the last value in the line is less than the first value in the next line then increases the next line by the value +10

```
a = np.array([[0, 1, 5, 2, 3],[4, 2,2, 3, 4],[0, 3, 5,6, 8],[5,2,1,2,4],[7,8,2,3,6]])
for k in range(a):
     j=np.where(a[k,-1] < a[k+1,0], a[k+1]+10,a)
     print(j)
```

it just gave me an error message

```
TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
```

input

```
[[0 1 5 2 3]
 [4 2 2 3 4]
 [0 3 5 6 8]
 [5 2 1 2 4]
 [7 8 2 3 6]]
```

I need
required output:

```
[[ 0  1  5  2  3]
 [14 12 12 13 14]
 [ 0  3  5  6  8]
 [ 5  2  1  2  4]
 [17 18 12 13 16]]
```

I only tried it from the first two lines and the result was that it changed the whole array

```
j=np.where(a[0,-1] < a[1,0], a[1]+10,a)
         print(j)
```

my output:

```
[[14 12 12 13 14]
 [14 12 12 13 14]
 [14 12 12 13 14]
 [14 12 12 13 14]
 [14 12 12 13 14]]
```

I also tried through if else but it didn't work

Comment: You say "increase by value +10" (4-> 14) but actually show the required output for *10 (4->40). Which is it?

Comment: I'm sorry, I corrected the question

Answer (score 3):

You can try the following:

```
>>> a[1:][a[:-1,-1] < a[1:, 0]] *= 10
array([[ 0,  1,  5,  2,  3],
       [40, 20, 20, 30, 40],
       [ 0,  3,  5,  6,  8],
       [ 5,  2,  1,  2,  4],
       [70, 80, 20, 30, 60]])
```

Where

```
>>> a[:-1,-1]  # Gives the value along last col from first to the second last row
array([3, 4, 8, 4])

>>> a[1:, 0]   # Gives the value along first col from second to the last row
array([4, 0, 5, 7])

>>> a[:-1,-1] < a[1:, 0] # Gives indices where cond==True, from 2nd to last row
array([ True, False, False,  True])

# Then we access these boolean indices, in slice `a[1:]` which gives 2nd to last row
```

**NOTE:** As pointed out by @GiovanniFrisson You have asked for `+10` which would mean `a[1:][a[:-1,-1] < a[1:, 0]] += 10`, but I have assumed here your output to be your desired outcome, hence used `*=10` which is multiplied by 10.

Comment: @Rusnàk Actually, based on your description should be a[1:][a[:-1,-1] < a[1:, 0]] += 10;
But or your expected output is wrong or your description is

Comment: this could be done for more matrices as well. somehow chain them?